# Running PHP Code Without Loading A New Page

Tags: php, cookies

This might be a dumb question, but I'm new to transferring data from the client side to the server side. I'm using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript#24103596) to create a cookie. Then I was going to use `$_COOKIE` in a separate PHP file to read the data from the cookie. Is it possible to run my PHP code without loading a new tab/window?

Comment: Post the code "here", not a link.

Comment: You would need to use ajax which is using JavaScript to make the request to the php page in the background instead of loading another page directly.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But it's probably not the best way to do it - a cookie is intended to be read repeatedly on every future page/session for its lifetime. If you want to simply transfer data between the front and backends, you'd probably be more interested in using AJAX: www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.

Comment: I suggest a read on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX ... w3schools is such trash ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the server return a [`204 No Content` response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204), or make the request with [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), or by loading an image, or by loading a new page in an iframe, or by making any other HTTP request that doesn't trigger a whole new page load.

… but there seems little point in storing data in a cookie (which is used when you want to include data in *every subsequent request*) and then sending it to PHP without caring about what the response it. Possibly you would be better of forgetting about the cookie and just using `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` to make a POST request with the data in the request body instead of in a cookie.

Answer (score -1):

You can send a POST/GET request to the target page using AJAX.

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
....
```

[Read more about Jquery's Ajax Here.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

You don't really need to use jQuery, you can use the standard [vanilla way.](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)

As for server-side, you can fetch data sent via AJAX with `$_POST['foo']`, `$_GET["bar"]`[...](http://php.net/manualreserved.variables.php)

Where 'foo' and 'bar' are the field names passed thought AJAX.

Comment: This is either a comment of a link only answer. Neither are very well respected when placed in an answer